# Call to a member function ipcr() on null when i print_r a value of the textbox

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Here's my create.blade.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    var x =0;  
    $(".add-row").click(function(){
        x++;
        $("table > tbody").append('<input class="form-control" type="text" name="MFI" placeholder="Major Final Output" id="MFI" value="Participate in school activities">'); 
    }); //add input box
});
```

NotesController.php

```
public function store(Request $request)
  print_r($_POST);
    $ipcrId = Note::find($request->ipcr_id);

    foreach ($request->MFI as $key => $value) {

        $ipcrId->ipcr()->create([

            'MFI' => $request->MFI[$key]    
            // repeat for other fields

        ]);

    }
```

Note.php

```
class Note extends Model
{
    protected $fillable= ['successIndicator','actualaccomplishments',
                        'distribution','Q1','E2','T3',' A4','Ave',
                        'Remarks','ipcr_id'];

    public function ipcr()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(ipcr::class);
    }
}
```

ipcrController.php

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $dataInput= $request->all();
    $user= Auth::user();
    $user->ipcr()->create($dataInput);

    //$sql = "insert ";

    //ipcr::create($dataInput);


    return redirect('/ipcr');
```

I get

> FatalErrorException in NotesController.php line 55: Call to a member function ipcr() on null

When I `print_r()` I get the value of the txtbox:

```
Array ( [MFI] => Array ( [0] => Participate in school activities ) 
        [_token] => mLuXcpnazy73KpKf1GY4WPLeVQcC1601KvbMHX4x 
    )
```

Comment: FatalErrorException in NotesController.php line 55:
Call to a member function ipcr() on null

Comment: when i printr i get the value of the txtbox 
Array ( [MFI] => Array ( [0] => Participate in school activities ) [_token] => mLuXcpnazy73KpKf1GY4WPLeVQcC1601KvbMHX4x ) 

how to i store it?

Comment: Please do not ask questions in comments. __EDIT__ your question instead.

Comment: print the request array and check if it is empty

Comment: not empty sir  . it will show but i guess my model or my controller are wrong